# Select date for second date. Twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

So I have a two datepickers, pretty simple stuff, to and from date...

Could you please tell me how to pass highlighted "startDate" to the date that was selected from the first datepicker.

Here is an image of a bug I'm trying to solve the date is set to current date (today), disbled date is OK, the date that should be highlighted is circled in blue:

[image]

And here is the source code:

```
    $("#mzti-start-date").datepicker({
      format: 'dd MM yyyy',
      startDate: date,
      autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function(dateEvent) {
      start_date = $("#mzti-start-date").val();
      $('#mzti-finish-date').datepicker('setStartDate', start_date);
    });

    $("#mzti-finish-date").datepicker({
      format: 'dd MM yyyy',
      autoclose: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There we go guys, solution:

```
    $("#mzti-start-date").datepicker({
      format: 'dd MM yyyy',
      startDate: date,
      autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function(dateEvent) {
      start_date = $("#mzti-start-date").val();
      $('#mzti-finish-date').datepicker('setStartDate', start_date);
      var iso_date = new Date(start_date);
      $('#mzti-finish-date').datepicker('setDate', iso_date);
    });
```

There is a definitely a niftier way to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with bootstrap datepicker (didn't actually realize there was one), but I think you just need to read the [docs](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and follow them more closely. For instance, you're passing some options to the first datepicker, but the docs don't list a "startDate" option (though perhaps it still works). My guess is the problem is this line:

```
$('#mzti-finish-date').datepicker('setStartDate', start_date);
```

There's no "setStartDate" method, so try this instead:

```
$('#mzti-finish-date').datepicker('setValue', start_date);
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to provide more information. It's a little difficult to know what you're asking.

Comment: It's actually in here, mate: https://bitbucket.org/simpler/bootstrap-datepicker/src/566a1d34905ca64c889aebec92935a322de5ec47/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js?at=master#cl-145

Comment: Interesting. I guess the documentation I was looking is incomplete (or corresponds to a different version). Glad you figured it out.